# Generalized method to get sum of any data type in java

Tags: java, oop, generics

I want a general method which can give me output for any data type passed to its arguments.

For example:

We have to write many same implementations for different data types.

```
class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int x=sum(1,2);
        double y=sum(1.11,2.22);
        String z=sum("1","2");
    }

    static public int sum(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }

    static public double sum(double a, double b) {
        return a + b;
    }

    static public String sum(String a, String b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Need only one method which can accept any data type and return the output.

Comment: Even for things that don't make any sense to be added together?

Comment: Not possible, not desirable.

Comment: @ayush If you are sure that both numbers input will be of same data type, using a `generic` method might help.

Comment: If you take a look at the `Arrays class` you will see that methods that do the same operation for primitive types need to be overloaded.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible because you can't add arbitrary objects using the `+` operator (see [Java specification for '+' operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18)).

If you don't care about losing precision in some cases, you could define the type of the parameters to be [`Number`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Number.html) and then call `doubleValue` and/ or `longValue` before doing the addition. The only other way is to write a separate method for each of the primitive types.

However, if you want to add arbitrary objects together, you could create an `Addable` interface which defines an `add(Addable other)` method and implement that method in your classes. I don't know how you would define such an addition, but ultimately that's up to you.

Some classes, like `BigInteger` already have such a method. It is, however, not defined by an interface and only takes objects of the same type.